# General wave function equates to one after equating Euler's identity. Why?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, mathematics, complex-numbers

Am typing on my phone, so apologies for any mistakes. Basically we know a general wave function taken as an example to be $\psi = e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$ where $k=2\pi/\lambda$ and $\omega=2\pi f$.

Euler's identity is $e^{2i\pi}=1$.

We can write the first equation as $e^{i2\pi(x/\lambda -ft)}$ where $e^{i2\pi}$ would be 1 making the whole equation 1, i.e., $\psi=1$.

This doesn't make sense. Is there something am missing about $\psi$ as my math is correct and I've shown it to my quantum professor and he is just as bamboozled. Can anybody make sense out of this?

Comment: This is more of a math question than a physics question. You are asking about wavefunctions, but this question doesn't depend on that.

Comment: This question has collected several votes for migration to [math.se], but it appears to fall under the category "Mathematics in the context of physics" which is listed as on topic in the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and I don't see any other reason for it to be considered off topic.

Comment: @DavidZ But this is a question about the math of complex numbers just applied to physics. It isn't a question that requires knowledge of physics like an actual "Mathematics in the context of physics" question typically would on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> We can write the first equation as $e^{i2\pi(x/\lambda -ft)}$ where
>   $e^{i2\pi}$ would be 1 making the whole equation 1, i.e., $\psi=1$.

First, $(kx-\omega t) = 2\pi(x/\lambda-ft)$ is equal to $2\pi$ only for *some* values of $x$ and $t$ but not for *all* values of $x$ and $t$. So it isn't true that $\psi=1$.

So where has your logic failed? By the law of exponents, we can write

$$1^{a\cdot b}=(1^a)^b=1^b=1$$

And, since $e^{i2\pi}=1$, it should be that

$$e^{i2\pi(x/\lambda -ft)}=(e^{i2\pi})^{(x/\lambda -ft)}=1^{(x/\lambda -ft)}=1$$

right? No! There's a subtle issue here due to the fact that [the natural log of a complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) is *multivalued*. From the Wikipedia article section [Exponentiation: Failure of power and logarithm identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities)

> The identity $(e^x)^y = e^{xy}$ holds for real numbers $x$ and $y$,
>   but assuming its truth for complex numbers leads to the following
>   paradox, discovered in 1827 by Thomas Clausen
>
> For any integer $n$, we have:
>
> $$e^{1 + 2 \pi i n} = e^1 e^{2 \pi i n} = e \cdot 1 = e$$
>
> $$\left(e^{1 + 2\pi i n}\right)^{1 + 2 \pi i n} = e\qquad
>  \mathrm{(taking\,the\,}(1 + 2 \pi i
>  n)\mathrm{-th\,power\,of\,both\,sides)}$$
>
> $$e^{1 + 4 \pi i n - 4 \pi^2 n^2} = e\qquad
>  \mathrm{(using\,}\left(e^x\right)^y =
>  e^{xy}\,\mathrm{and\,expanding\,the\,exponent)}$$
>
> $$e^1 e^{4 \pi i n} e^{-4 \pi^2 n^2} = e\qquad
>  \mathrm{(using\,}e^{x+y} = e^x e^y)$$
>
> $$e^{-4 \pi^2 n^2} = 1\qquad \mathrm{(dividing\,by\,e})$$
>
> but this is false when the integer $n$ is nonzero.
>
> The error is the following: by definition, $e^y$ is a notation for
>   $\exp(y)$, a true function, and $x^y$ is a notation for $\exp(y\log
>  x)$, which is a multi-valued function. Thus the notation is ambiguous
>   when $x=e$. Here, before expanding the exponent, the second line
>   should be
>
> $$\exp\left((1 + 2\pi i n)\log \exp(1 + 2\pi i n)\right) = \exp(1 +
>  2\pi i n)$$
>
> Therefore, when expanding the exponent, one has implicitly supposed
>   that $\log \exp z =z$ for complex values of $z$, which is wrong, as
>   the complex logarithm is multivalued. In other words, the wrong
>   identity $(e^x)^y = e^{xy}$ must be replaced by the identity
>
> $$\left(e^x\right)^y = e^{y\log e^x}$$
>
> which is a true identity between multivalued functions.

Comment: I redid the math using the paradox you presented and the problem still persists. You can write psi as e^((i)(2pi(x/lamdba -ft))), which as per the last statement of the proof would be written as e^((2pi(x/lamdba -ft))(loge^i)). When you compute loge^i and put that in the equation, you end up in a loop.

Comment: Basically, e^((2pi(x/lamdba -ft))(loge^i)) where loge^i = b*i, makes the equation e^((2pi(x/lamdba -ft))b*i, and then we reapply the law as done before, we get e^((2pi(x/lamdba -ft))b*(loge^i)), and the loop keeps on repeating, and you keep getting higher powers of b with each loop. I think I will post this on mathematics.

Comment: @SamarthAgnihotri, please use mathjax for your equations so that they are readable to me and others. Honestly, very few here are willing to take the time to wade through something like "psi as  e^((i)(2pi(x/lamdba -ft)))" when it's just as easy for you to write \psi = e^{i2\pi(x/\lambda - ft)} which, if you enclose that within dollar signs, renders as $\psi = e^{i2\pi(x/\lambda - ft)}$

Comment: @SamarthAgnihotri The mistake is that you are still assuming that $e^{xy}=(e^{x})^y$. If you started with $(e^x)^y$ then you could apply what this answer discusses. But that is not what your original expression is. Your original expression is just of the form $e^{xy}$.